# Slit Slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although someone had the same issue I see those solutions don't work for me. This works 100% on my local server and when applied online it shows this. The coding taken from the tutorial for slit slider.

http://www.designelite.co.za/PARTY/index.html

Anyone telling me what the problem could be. If it works 100% on my server shouldn't it work online.

Any help will do.

Comment: i can't see jquery script linked!!

Comment: I see a js error in console, TypeError: Modernizr is undefined "this.transEndEventName = this.transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transitio..."

Comment: you have wrong permissions on `Modernizr` file so server returns 403, fix permissions and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have permission error on your console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

grant access rights to the web server account and this should fix it.

as Armen Asriyan said

Comment: I added permissions to it and still doesn't work. It reads TypeError: Modernizr is undefined. How do I define it? Could there be coding I need to update.

Comment: Okay seems to be working now. Thanks everyone for your help. Much appreciated.